# Spring JDBC dependency issues

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to set up my project to use Spring JDBC and I am running into issues regarding dependencies.

In my pom file I got:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And when I try to set up my spring.xml configurations for `DriverManagerDataSource`, I get an error that can't find the dependency.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
```

Also, I can't instantiate `DriverManagerDataSource`.

---

Seems like I need to add the following into my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but why? It already has 4.3.2.RELEASE version? Why does it also need 3.0.5 version?

Comment: Why the downvote? It really frustrates me when people downvote without giving a reason.

Comment: How about to update your question with: 1) Error you are getting. 2) Full configuration of data source. 3) More details. Like full dependencies list. From here, I can't even say that you have a MySQL driver. This is simply poorly composed question that nobody is going to benefit even if you get an answer.

Comment: @BranislavLazic 1. I already provided the error which is maven can't find the dependency for DriverManagerDataSource. 2. Why do you need the full configuration of data source if my project can't even find the dependency? That part is irrelevant.

Comment: And having a MySQL driver is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use DriverManagerDataSource.

> Only use the DriverManagerDataSource class should only be used for
>   testing purposes since it does not provide pooling and will perform
>   poorly when multiple requests for a connection are made.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html

Follow Spring examples and use BasicDataSource instead:

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Comment: Wow. I was using an old tutorial. Thanks!